# Visual Studio JIT Debugger hangs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, jit

I've always used System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() as a quick way to debug web services. I get a dialog asking me to choose a debugger, I pick "New instance of Visual Studio" and it fires up VS and lets me step through the code.

That has suddenly stopped working. Now I get the dialog, and choose Visual Studio, and the VS splash screen appears, and then it just hangs. The dialog window says "Not Responding" and I have to force it to close. Even then, a VS instance is left hanging around in Task Manager and I have to kill it manually.

I've tried repairing Visual Studio, and uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio, and nothing fixes it.

In desperation, I completely flattened my PC and reinstalled everything from scratch. It lasted about a day and then JIT debugging started hanging again. I was on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 17.4.1 before, and I'm on Windows 11 and Visual Studio 17.4.2 now.

To make sure that it's not a problem with some particular code, I created a one-line console app System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); and that crashes just the same.

Has anybody experienced anything similar, or have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you start VS first and then attach with the already running instance? Has the advantage that you can even have your project/solution open already.

Comment: Is this a native (C++) service or managed?

Comment: Embarrassingly, I didn't actually know that it was possible to attach the process to an existing instance of VS. I've tried that now and it works so thank you for that! I've now got a way around the problem at least. It's all .NET managed code.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Done. I was not really expecting this to work so flawlessly for the OP.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Done. I still haven't figured out what caused the original problem (or how it managed to re-occur after a full OS reinstall!) but I have a support ticket open with the VS support team so if we get to the bottom of it, I'll add the details here.

Comment: In my case it doesn't even list running VS2022 instances so I could select from. The only option is a new VS2022 instance which it hangs on starting. Any help on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why that fails, but I suggest to attach to a running instance of Visual Studio instead. Start Visual Studio first, and then when the "launch debugger" window appears, select the running VS instance. Preferably, you should even open the correct solution/project first. If you attach to that instance, all your source code and the project structure is available for debugging.

Another alternative: Instead of using `Debugger.Launch()`, use a code snipped such as

```cs
while (!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

at the beginning of your program and attach the debugger from within Visual Studio (using the menu option Debug->Attach to process)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and after updated to VS version 17.4.4 the issue disappeared. All good now.