# Visual studio 2022 hangs on Debug.Launch()

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2022

Summary:

The problem is when I launch an app which has `Debug.Launch()` with a new instance of visual studio 2022 [17.4.3] or visual studio 2022 Preview [17.5.0 Preview 2.0] it hangs forever. Same for visual studio 2019 [16.11.22]. I originally had it in source generator [build time]. So then I tested it with a console application as well to see if I get the same result (which I do get).

Steps:

1. Create Console App.
2. Add the following lines :

```
#if DEBUG
    if(!Debugger.IsAttached) Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

3. Build the solution (in Debug).
4. Start exe from debug folder.
5. Try to open with new instance of visual studio 2022.
   Visual studio hangs forever.

I also opened the following [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-use-source-generator-visual-st/10243680).

Already tried the following:

- Restart Pc
- Deleted vs Folder
- Repair Visual Studio (twice)
- DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
- sfc /scannow
- Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool
- Turn windows feature on or off => .NET Framework options turned off and back on (with restarting)
- Restored pc-image to version when it was working => still fails
- Copying folder to VM and installing latest Visual Studio 2022 and running it there. => Also fails

Comment: Maybe your code run last succesBuild. Can you check it?

Comment: Why do you want to do in this way?

Comment: @Xeo Because it's the only way to debug source generators appearently. Also it should just work?

Comment: @EminNiftiyev Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but maybe the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706908/visual-studio-jit-debugger-hangs/74712988#74712988 helps you?

Comment: @PMF What process do I attach it to? Because I want to use it for source generation debugging and now it just hangs mid-build. Even if I attach a different visual studio instance to the Rosalyn code analyzer process it continuous to hang.

Comment: @TymeB look at this http://www.vgizy.com/recover-the-there-were-build-errors-would-you-like-to-continue-and-run-the-last-successful-build-dialog-in-visual-studio/#:~:text=Tools%20%3E%20Options%20%3E%20Projects%20and%20Solutions%20%3E%20Build%20and%20Run&text=The%20selection%20in%20the%20second,with%20the%20last%20successful%20build.

Comment: @EminNiftiyev The build never failed though. The build always succeeds (except in my source generator project). But when Debugger.Launch() gets hit, it throws an exception. Its most likely a framework file got corrupted. because everything worked fine Tuesday.

Comment: Actually if one more times you get error. And click `run succesful build`. Then you change some code.  Never run your new code. Cause Evevrytime run your last code (worked Thueday code). Before you changed code. But never builded new code block.

Comment: @EminNiftiyev Except I never got the prompt because the build didn't failed. Also my settings are still on prompt to launch. So after building any solution it would give the prompt. And finally I have the issue on all solutions even newly created ones.

Comment: @TymeB It seems you would need to attach to the process name displayed in the message ("ServiceHub.RoslycodeanalisisService.exe"). But I agree, could be caused by some framework corruption. I'd just reinstall the .NET SDK (for the version you use).

Comment: @TymeB the problem isn't the exception, it's the fact you're trying to create and debug a source generator. That's important information that **must** be included in the question, otherwise it makes no sense. - why *shouldn't* `Debugger.Launch` through if there's no debugger? What debugger? VS Code? WinDbg? Rider? Visual Studio? Console applications aren't source generators either, so *why* create a console application that's guaranteed to fail? Source generators run at build time, not run time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that when I launch it  with a new instance of visual studio 2022 it hangs forever. Same for visual studio 2019. I originally had it in source generator [build time]. So then I tested it with a console application as well to see if I get the same result (which I do get). I changed the title so it's more clear now.

Comment: Write all that in the question itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is it ok now?

Comment: Are you following [this blog post?](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/debug-code-gen/) That uses a .NET Standard *library*, not a console application. So does [this guide](https://github.com/JoanComasFdz/dotnet-how-to-debug-source-generator-vs2022). A console or test projects are used to test the generator, they don't include `Debugger.Launch`. The generator will be called when you rebuild the test/console project, not when you actually run it

Comment: `Is it ok now?` not really - I doubt anyone would guess this is about source generators if I hadn't added the tag based on the comments. I wouldn't understand what you do *at all* if I didn't google for `Debug source code generator` and found the articles I linked to. Those articles **don't** call `Launch` in the Console. Only inside the Source Generator. Why did you try calling `Launch` in the test project instead?

Comment: One can only guess that you have a source generator project, that you tried to follow *some* guide and when that failed, you put `Launch` in the test project, which isn't what the guides show at all. Then, instead of rebuilding your project to kick off the source generator, you tried to launch it, which won't call the generator at all. Instead, `Launch` does what it's meant to do - crash the program, causing any configured debugger to start. If none is configured, the program simply crashes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I found those articles and those work for debugging a source generator. But my issue is still that `Debug.Launch()` still doen't work on any project. And the reason why I tried it this way, is because I was watching a youtube video where they did it this way and it was working.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this was the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pF1Qh2Ty7MQ) and also in this [git repo](https://github.com/EngRajabi/Enum.Source.Generator/blob/master/Supernova.Enum.Generators/EnumSourceGenerator.cs) you can you see they did it as well. But like I said. Debugging the source generator is not the primary issue here. Also I'm having this issue on multiple computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing an older version of visual studio (Visual Studio 2022 [17.3.6] Professional) I could open open the console.exe with `Debug.Launch()`. And the hanging was resolved.

Since you can't install an older community version of visual studio you need to install a professional version.

You can download it from here [Microsoft release history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history).

Comment: We had a similar issue running VS Professional 17.6.1...but also in VS Professional 17.5.3.  Having also seen this note on MS' board (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1289936/visual-studion-2022-version-17-6-hangs-on-buildcle?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1257679#newest-answer-comment) I believe something happens in VS in general, not one particular version.

Comment: I might have to wipe windows and start again :(